# \slash allows for hyphenation of only the word on its left; how to fix it for the right-hand word

Tags: punctuation, hyphenation

I often use `\slash` to allow for linebreak after the slash. However I found that `\slash` doesn't allow for hyphenation of the word to its right, while it does for the word on its left. How do I use `\slash` in a way (this can be a different macro, if necessary) that hyphenation points on both sides are preserved?

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\begin{document}

\noindent qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq addition\slash{}subtraction

\noindent qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq addition\slash{}subtraction

\noindent qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq addition\slash{}subtraction

\noindent qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq addition\slash{}subtraction

\noindent qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq addition\slash{}subtraction

\noindent qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq addition\slash{}subtraction

\end{document}
```

In this example, the last line hyphenates after "ad-", the line before linebreaks after the slash, and none of the previous lines hyphenate "subtraction".

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
\def\Slash{\slash\hspace{0pt}}
```

Comment: Excellent, I've just checked, and this has the desired results.