# Reset an active character in \href

Tags: hyperref, catcodes

In my document, the symbol `/` is active. This leads to the problem with links. Instead of the slash they contain expansion of the slash.

Wanted:

`http://aaa/ggg/ddd/`

Got:

`http://www.\discretionary%20{.com/}{}{/
}\discretionary%20{/}{}{/}aaa\discretio
nary%20{/}{}{/}ggg\discretionary%20{/}{
}{/}ddd\discretionary%20{/}{}{/}`

How to get the desired result?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\def\SlashDesc{\discretionary{/}{}{/}}
\AtBeginDocument{\catcode`\/=\active}
\catcode`\/=\active
\def/{\SlashDesc}

\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\def/{X}} % Doesn't help

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{5cm}
\lipsum*[75]
\href{http://aaa/ggg/ddd/}{aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee/fff/ggg/hhh/iii/jjj/kkk/lll}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You shouldn't activate `/` in the first place.

Comment: You can try `\href{http://aaa/ggg/ddd/}{\url{aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee/fff/ggg/hhh/iii/jjj/kkk/lll}}` without using an active `/` character

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't be activating `/` in the first place. The control sequence `\slash` already does (better) what you want for `\SlashDesc`.

If you insist for this, then you have to add the setting of `/` to the `\hyper@normalise` list. Here's a way; I have also streamlined your definition of the active slash.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\let\ORIG@hyper@normalise\hyper@normalise
\def\hyper@normalise{%
  % make / other
  \begingroup\@makeother\/%
  % now expand the original and gobble the leading \begingroup
  \expandafter\@gobble\ORIG@hyper@normalise}
\makeatother

\AtBeginDocument{\catcode`\/=\active}
\begingroup\lccode`~=`/ \lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\slash

\begin{document}

\makeatletter

\begin{minipage}{5cm}
\lipsum*[75]%
\href{http://aaa/ggg/ddd/}{aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee/fff/ggg/hhh/iii/jjj/kkk/lll}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

(Sorry, but the interface for adding pictures seems not to be working.)

Comment: Thanks. The next level of complications is `\def\aaa{minipage code is here}\aaa`. The link now is `http://www.\penalty%20\exhyphenpenalty%20.com/\penalty%20\exhyphenpenalty%20aaa/\penalty%20\exhyphenpenalty%20ggg/\penalty%20\exhyphenpenalty%20ddd/\penalty%20\exhyphenpenalty%20`

Comment: @olpa  No, that will definitely not work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks `egreg` a lot for the suggestion how to inject into `\hyper@normalise`. It is a new and very useful trick for me.

The solution can be generalized for other active symbols as well.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\let\ORIG@hyper@normalise\hyper@normalise
\def\ORIG@slash@letter{/}
\catcode`\/=\active
\edef\hyper@normalise{%
  \begingroup
  \def\noexpand/{\ORIG@slash@letter}%
  \noexpand\expandafter\noexpand\@gobble\noexpand\ORIG@hyper@normalise}
\makeatother

% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97310/
\AtBeginDocument{\catcode`\/=\active \def/{\slash\hspace{0pt}}}

\begin{document}

\def\aaa{
\begin{minipage}{5cm}
\lipsum*[75]%
\href{http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160031/}{aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee/fff/ggg/hhh/iii/jjj/kkk/lll}
\end{minipage}
}
\aaa

\end{document}
```